# Hortonworks sandbox- cannot kinit because ambari-qa-Sandbox@DOMAIN.COM should be ambari-qa-sandbox@DOMAIN.COM

Tags: kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I have been playing around with the sandbox and am having an issue after i enabled kerberos where services were not starting.

I found that the reason is because it is trying to kinit like so:

```
/usr/bin/kinit -kt /etc/security/keytabs/smokeuser.headless.keytab ambari-qa-Sandbox@HORTONWORKS.COM;
```

And it should be:

```
/usr/bin/kinit -kt /etc/security/keytabs/smokeuser.headless.keytab ambari-qa-sandbox@HORTONWORKS.COM;
```

(notice lowercase s in sandbox)

I have change it to lowercase in Ambari for the user "hbase-sandbox@HORTONWORKS.COM" under hbase>configs>advanced but i cannot find where to change it for ambari-qa-Sandbox which causes Zookeeper not to start.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, you cannot change it in Ambari directly however you can change it using ./configs.sh like so:

```
cd /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts
```

Details on how to use configs.sh can be found by:

```
./configs.sh usage
```

Then use something like this to change the value:

```
./configs.sh -u admin -p password set localhost sandbox cluster-env smokeuser_principal_name ambari-qa-sandbox@HORTONWORKS.COM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this directly in the Ambari UI.

Login to the Ambari UI and click the Admin tab at the top right and select the kerberos option.

On this screen you will see the principals and other kerberos configuration for the services in the cluster and can modify them as necessary.